# Why .NET doesn't have built-in Observer pattern like Java?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, observer-pattern, .net-2.0

I wonder why .NET framework doesn't have pair (Observer/Observable) interfaces similar to Java's feature?

**EDIT:**
yes i know about events and delegates but using those interfaces is a simple and bookish approach of this DP isn't it?

Comment: "using those interfaces is a simple and bookish approach of this DP isn't it?" - if that's the question, then this isn't much of a question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .NET 4 *it does*: [`System.IObservable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx) and [`System.IObserver<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) (which are a [Dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28mathematics%29) of `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`). Look at the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) project for compositional use of these interfaces with asynchronous events.

More generally, the Observer pattern is better served in .NET with events.

Answer (score 6):

Because .NET has actual events and delegates. Java lacks these basic constructs and has to resort to ugly hacks (your Observable interface) to pass "method pointers" around.

Comment: ugly hacks? so why in NET4.0 they introduce Observable interfaces? (see next answer)

Comment: @Arseny - they have similar names, but work quite differently.

Comment: This is a matter of interpretation, some languages do it one way, some the other. The statement is, IMHO, not very helpful ... and .Net does provide an IObservable to provide for this feature.

Comment: This is bad to use bad words about good languages, created by good guys.

Comment: There are other uses for the observable pattern in C#, for example the Observable Collections in WPF. But for your question in particular, C# has a better alternative in its very syntax (and il-asm code).

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same thing with events and spaghetti code and they will drive you crazy trying to cleanup after them as they lock themselves into your non-disposable memory blocks.

If you don't yet have .Net 4, use the well know observer pattern and type it out the old-fashioned way - by hand.

The observer pattern is not simply writing events longhand, it's the basis for re-usable and extendable code. It is also a more decoupled and elegant approach to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same sort of thing with Events. Also you can easily implement your own Observer pattern. It has to be one of the easiest patterns to implement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

As for the why part. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Where have you been.  It is called events and delegates.  Yes, it is a hack, but it works and more people prefer to use the language built in features over a design pattern you must type in yourself.  The language feature is already debugged and ready to go.